# Tire pressure and new tires

Tags: tires, gmc, pressure, terrain

I bought new tires in September. I have returned to the place I purchased them many times due to malfunctions. I feel like I am putting air in my tires all of the time. I know with temperature change that the PSI will change. I don't know if I should go back and have them remount the tires? It seems like my tire sensor is always on due to low PSI.

Comment: I would go somewhere else and have tires re-mounted and then give them the bill...

Comment: If the wheels are rotated and the wheel sensors not re calibrated it can cause the sensor light.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a old fashion tire gauge, fill the tires to the required pressure and monitor the tire pressure. Determine which tires are actually causing the problem, check them daily. Once you get some information on them you can go back to the installer. You could have picked up a nail somewhere or you could have a bad sensor. good luck